# matplotlib color gradient between two colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want a color gradient between black and red in matplotlib, where the low values are black and become more and more red with increasing Y-value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xvals = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
yvals = xvals
plt.plot(xvals, yvals, "r")
axes = plt.axes()
plt.show()
```

What do I have to change to get such a color gradient?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the matplotlib documentation you can check [this link](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html) as an example.

To create that colormap you just need to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np

colors = [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0)] # first color is black, last is red
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
        "Custom", colors, N=20)
mat = np.indices((10,10))[1]
plt.imshow(mat, cmap=cm)
plt.show()
```

This results in this:

[image: Custom colormap from black to red]

Comment: Thank you. This method can be used to define a color map for use with Seaborn heatmaps.