# How to choose colormaps in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am searching for a color combination option that starts with whitish and ends with red, and in between more colors. In Matplotlib colormaps option I searched but didn't get that. Any way to do the same?

[image: Example colorbar]

Comment: @harshbarshan You can develop custom `cmap`  using `LinearSegmentedColormap` in `matplotlib.colors`. Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57268627/matplotlib-color-gradient-between-two-colors) and this [link](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom colormap from white and the color of 'jet'.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 1))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4)
cmap_jet = plt.get_cmap('jet')
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['white'] + list(cmap_jet(np.linspace(0, 1, 7))))
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(1, 2.5)), cax=ax,
             orientation='horizontal', ticks=np.arange(1, 2.5001, .3))
plt.show()
```

[image: custom colormap white+jet]

To get a wider range between white and the start of the jet colormap, you could provide a list of tuples to `LinearSegmentedColormap`:

```py
blue_start = 0.3
color_list = [(0, 'white')] + list( zip(np.linspace(blue_start, 1, 10), cmap_jet(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))))
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', color_list)
```

[image: longer range between white and blue]